# Increase resolution of bar chart

Tags: r

Im constructing a bar chart, but the resolution is very poor, which is a problem as I want to use the chart for a research paper. Can anyone help me increase the resolution of the chart?

Im using the following code:

```
# Create the input vectors.
colors = c("black","grey")
years <- c("2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021")
sectors <- c("Financials","Industrials")

# Give the chart file a name
png(file = "Panel B.png")

# Create the bar chart
barplot(PanelB, main = "Panel B. Numbers of corporate green bonds issued", 
        names.arg = years, xlab = "Years", ylab = "Number of green bonds issued", col = colors)

# Add the legend to the chart
legend("topleft", sectors, cex = 1.3, fill = colors)

# Save the file
dev.off()
```

Data:

```
PanelB <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 16, 2, 12, 6, 14, 38, 29, 56, 31, 
181, 59, 251, 58), .Dim = c(2L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"
)))
```

Comment: `?png` is a help doc that contains several options for the output file. Did you check there?

Comment: I'd suggest using `?pdf` for publications, esp if the plots are just vectors anyways like bar plots, heatmaps etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `png("Panel B.png", width = 6, height = 4, units = 'in', res = 300)`

More documentation on how to create higher resolution figures you will find  [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/03/high-resolution-figures-in-r/)

```
PanelB <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 16, 2, 12, 6, 14, 38, 29, 56, 31, 
                            181, 59, 251, 58), .Dim = c(2L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("2013", 
                                                                                          "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"
                            )))

#Create the input vectors.

colors = c("black","grey")
years <- c("2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021")
sectors <- c("Financials","Industrials")

#Give the chart file a name

png(file = "Panel B.png")
png("Panel B.png", width = 6, height = 4, units = 'in', res = 300)

#Create the bar chart

barplot(PanelB, main = "Panel B. Numbers of corporate green bonds issued", 
        names.arg = years, xlab = "Years", ylab = "Number of green bonds issued", col = colors)

#Add the legend to the chart

legend("topleft", sectors, cex = 1.3, fill = colors)



#Save the file

dev.off()
```

**New:**
[image]

**Old:**

[image]